# The EditText widget doesnot work properly, how to make it work?

Tags: java, android

I am making a length converter program in android studio, in which I have 2 spinners & 2 EditText. I've used EditText widget to let the user input any value, when I run the code on my device using USB debugger, when I try to input value, the app gets stuck & after a while it crashes. Please help me with any suggestion on how to make it work properly. 
Below is the code reference which I've tried:

XML part :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerconverter1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:ms_background_color="#E3E0E3E3" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputlength1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_gv_round"
            android:hint="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
    <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerconverter2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:ms_background_color="#E3E0E3E3" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputlength2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_gv_round"
            android:hint="@string/_0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
```

Java Part :

```
public class LengthConverterFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText inputlength1, inputlength2;
    private MaterialSpinner spinnerconverter1, spinnerconverter2;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_length_converter, container, false);
        inputlength1 = root.findViewById(R.id.inputlength1);
        inputlength2 = root.findViewById(R.id.inputlength2);
        imghand = root.findViewById(R.id.imghand);
        spinnerconverter1 = root.findViewById(R.id.spinnerconverter1);
        spinnerconverter2 = root.findViewById(R.id.spinnerconverter2);
        spinnerconverter1.setItems("Nanometres", "Micrometres", "Millimetres", "Centimetres", "Metres", "Kilometres", "Inches", "Feets", "Yards",
                "Miles", "Nautical Miles", "Lunar Distance");

        spinnerconverter2.setItems("Nanometres", "Micrometres", "Millimetres", "Centimetres", "Metres", "Kilometres", "Inches", "Feets", "Yards",
                "Miles", "Nautical Miles", "Lunar Distance");
        inputlength1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String l1 = inputlength1.getText().toString();
                if (l1.length() > 0) {
                    if (spinnerconverter1.getText().equals("Nanometres") && spinnerconverter2.getText().equals("Nanometres")) {
                        inputlength2.setText("" + l1);
                    } else if (spinnerconverter1.getText().equals("Nanometres") && spinnerconverter2.getText().equals("Micrometres")) {
                        String res = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(l1) * 0.001);
                        inputlength2.setText("" + res);
                    } 
                } else if (l1.length() == 0) {
                    inputlength2.setText("0");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        inputlength2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String l2 = inputlength2.getText().toString();
                if (l2.length() > 0) {
                    if (spinnerconverter2.getText().equals("Nanometres") && spinnerconverter1.getText().equals("Nanometres")) {
                        inputlength1.setText("" + l2);
                    } else if (spinnerconverter2.getText().equals("Nanometres") && spinnerconverter1.getText().equals("Micrometres")) {
                        String res = String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(l2) * 0.001);
                        inputlength1.setText("" + res);
                    }
                }else if (l2.length() == 0) {
                    inputlength1.setText("0");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }

}
```

Comment: _"when I try to input value, the app gets stuck & after a while it crashes."_ Are you perhaps getting an infinite feedback loop with the two `TextWatchers`? Modifying the text programmatically also triggers the `TextWatcher`.

Comment: You can check the crash details with the instructions in [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).